# How do I add SwipeRefreshLayout to my layout?(Without list/gridview)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I'm developing a weather app and I'm done with the networking(it can search and display the data for any city, and can also display the icons as well). I'm trying to add a `swiperefreshlayout` to the xml in fragment so that I can refresh the app from time to time and update the app data. But when I checked the official documentation for it i.e https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface, they said
"You enable this behavior by adding the widget to your layout file as the parent of a ListView or GridView". Meanwhile, I don't use either of those, I only use constraint layout and nestedscrollview, so I tried adding the SwipeRefreshLayout i.e

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/alerts_swiperefresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

both as parent and child of my constraint layout but it covers the whole xml layout and only it is reflecting in both cases. Is there any possibility of adding it to my layout? (Without list/gridview). If there is, please how can I do it? otherwise what other steps should I follow?

Here is the layout:

fragment_first.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".first.FirstFragment">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/current"
            android:textColor="#FF3D19"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="358dp"
            android:layout_height="337dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/orange_panel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/orange_panel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="@string/sunrise"
            android:textColor="#0aff69"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_arrow"
            app:tint="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
            android:text="@string/sunset"
            android:textColor="#ff0061"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="151dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rise_panel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rise_panel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="151dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/set_panel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/set_panel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/weather_conditions"
            android:textColor="#4230FF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_width="358dp"
            android:layout_height="337dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/blue_panel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue_panel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="@string/temperature"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/humidity"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView23" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/wind_speed"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/visibility"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/pressure"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/cloud"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView22" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sun"
            android:contentDescription="@string/current_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/current_temp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/current_output"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/small_sun"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rise_sun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:text="@string/rise_time"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView14" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/small_sun"
            android:contentDescription="@string/set_sun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:text="@string/set_time"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/temp_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/press_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/humid_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/ws_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/visi_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:text="@string/cloud_out"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView34" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: If you [look](https://androidx.de/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) at `SwipeRefreshLayout` you will notice it's a regular `ViewGroup` that implements a few traits `NestedScrollingParent` and `NestedScrollingChild`. In it's javadocs it states "The SwipeRefreshLayout should be used whenever the user can refresh the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture". It doesn't expect that the content is a List of any sort. It's just a "wrapper" around your layout so an "overscroll" triggers the callback.

Comment: @martinmarconcini Okay I can see that, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `SwipeRefreshLayout` without `RecyclerView`, `ListView` or `GridView`

`SwipeRefreshLayout` is basically used for refresh the content of a view with the vertical gesture feature.

Add `SwipeRefreshLayout` as parent of `NestedScrollView` if layout has scroll, If layout is not scrollable then just add `SwipeRefreshLayout` as parent of `Layout`

**For Example - If screen is scrollable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".first.FirstFragment">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <!--Your sub views-->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**For Example - If screen is not scrollable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".first.FirstFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <!--Your sub views-->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**How to stop refreshing SwipeRefreshLayout:**

You need to add `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` to stop refreshing

For example: I added handler thread in class to stop refreshing of SwipeRefreshLayout

```
    SwipeRefreshLayout realSwipe = findViewById(R.id.real_swipe);

    realSwipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // perform you action here for ex. add refresh screen code here
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // this code is for stop refreshing icon, After 1000 ms automatically refresh icon will stop
                    realSwipe.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, I tried your suggestion and these are my observations so far: 1. It shows a question sign on the layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3bpC.png, I don't know if it's because I didn't write any code programmatically. 2. It takes forever to refresh on my screen and doesn't eventually refresh(i.e the refresh icon just keeps turning till I close the app) meanwhile my network is good and 3. It couldn't recognize this code tools:context=".first.FirstFragment"> so I added it to the constraint layout instead. Meanwhile, I get no compile/run time errors

Comment: @RichardWilson, For Point `1` - Please check what message is showing  on click of question mark `2` - Please check edited answer. `3` - `tools:context` is define which Fragment or Activity is associated with layout, for more info check this link - https://blog.mindorks.com/what-is-tools-context-in-android-layout-files

Comment: Okay, point 2 is fixed, thanks. And I now understand 3, it's right also. Thanks too. For point 1, no message was shown on the click of the question mark.

Comment: i cant see real_swipe id on xml ... are you sure this piece of code work ???